# Generating multiple keys to decrypt one encrypted file

Tags: encryption, keys

I've come across this particular design where I have one file encrypted.

Then multiple people may want to access the file and I want to generate an individual key for each person, but each individual key should be able to totally decrypt the file.

Is there some encryption design that allow that?

Regards

Comment: Anything wrong with the basic: each person has a key $K_i$, the file is encrypted under a per-file random key $K$; then $K$ is encrypted with each of the individual $K_i$ yielding $K'_i$, and the $K'_i$ are included with the encrypted file as a header? If we make the $K_i$ assymetric keys pairs, this is what OpenPGP/GPG does.

Comment: [Broadcast encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcast_encryption) is designed to help with this sort of scenario.